# Latex/MathJax is broken in preview

Tags: bug, status-completed

Latex and MathJax preview don't seem to work anymore when asking/editing/answering questions.

Comment: Broken on Chrome 10.0.648.204 on MacOSX

Answer (score 4):

This was a regression - the CDN version of MathJax wasn't wired up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Either very slow or broken on FF 3.6.16 on Mac OS, too.

And it was working last night. Did something change recently?